# corrupted size vs. prev_size in c++.Double pointer problem

Tags: c++, pointers, resize, size

(I am new at C++)

Currently I am using double pointers to read a file which reads the size of the matrix, but when I read a new file with a diferent size of the last one corrupted size vs. prev_size pops up. I guess the problem is because

I read the file here:

```
SolucioU::SolucioU(string fitxer, int costM, int difM)
{
    ifstream f(fitxer);
    int x, y;
    int edificis, valor;
    bool trobat = false;
    Posicio p, ini;
    int i = 0;
    costMax = costM;
    difMax = difM;
    if (not f.is_open())  throw ("El fitxer no es pot obrir.Revisa el nom o els permisos. ");
    f >> midax >> miday;
    reserva();
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < miday; j++) {
            f >> matriu[i][j];
            usat[i][j] = false;
            edifici[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    f >> x >> y;
    recorregut.push_back(Posicio(x, y));
    usat[x][y] = true;
    cost = 10;
    dif = matriu[x][y];
    f >> edificis;
    if (edificis != 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < edificis; k++) {
            f >> x >> y >> valor;
            edifici[x][y] = valor;
        }
    }
    f.close();  
}
```

I guess the problem can be here, where i declare the size of the pointers.

```
void SolucioU::reserva(){

    matriu = new int* [midax - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        matriu[i] = new int[miday + 1];

    usat = new bool* [midax - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        usat[i] = new bool[miday + 1];
    
    edifici = new int* [midax - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        edifici[i] = new int[miday + 1];
}
```

Comment: `recorregut` -- what variable type is this?  If it's a vector, then why didn't you use vector in your second set of code?  `std::vector<int> matriu;...matriu.resize(midax - 1);`, etc.  Then all of those issues you are having are minimized or completely go away.

Comment: Similar to the previous comment - try to avoid manual memory allocation. In modern C++ it's very rare to use `new`, or even more - it could be perceived as a bad practice. Also in Your sample there are memory leaks. To have a 2-dimensional int container, use: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. In Your code I can see that, You're allocating an array of size `midax - 1`, but accessing indexes as to `midax - 1`, so too much by one.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie private:
vector<Posicio> recorregut;

Comment: And position is a pair of ints

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give You a snippet that should help You with this problem.

```
 // Somewhere in the code:
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> matriu;
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> usat;
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> edifici;
//

void reserva(){
    matriu = {};
    matriu.reserve(midax);
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        matriu.push_back(std::vector<int>(miday + 1, 0));
        
    usat = {};
    usat.reserve(midax);
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        usat.push_back(std::vector<int>(miday + 1, 0));
    
    edifici = {};
    edifici.reserve(midax);
    for (int i = 0; i < midax; i++)
        edifici.push_back(std::vector<int>(miday + 1, 0));
}
```

A few advices:
As I wrote in the comment - try avoid using `new` as much as possible. It's very bug-prone. Use structures or smart pointers to avoid memory leak.

If You need to use `new[]`, ensure that there is a corresponding `delete[]`.

Try to code in english, it will be easier to share Your code with other people.